# Android Toast from Listener using object

Tags: java, android

I was just experimenting in android spinner and i came around this weird app crash problem.

This is what i use by default to reference the class containing methods:
**sr.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);**
This works super fine

But when i change the method of referencing to this:
**sr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MainActivity());**

**EDIT**  :
Why should we pass **this**
Why can't we pass **new MainActivity()** ?

This error is thrown if a Toast is used:
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)**

Whole Code:

```
package com.example.defaultspinner;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{
    Spinner sr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sr = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp);
        String[] days = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ar = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.single_row, days);
        sr.setAdapter(ar);
        sr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MainActivity());  //passing new MainActivity() instead of this (it may be the problem)
        System.out.println("THIS -> " + this);     //com.example.defaultspinner.MainActivity@3b90554d
        System.out.println("NEW -> " + new MainActivity());  //com.example.defaultspinner.MainActivity@1475b903
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        String tm = "VALUE -> " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        System.out.println("THIS-> " + MainActivity.this);    //out -> com.example.defaultspinner.MainActivity@210b457b
        System.out.println("APP -> " + getApplicationContext());       //out -> null
        System.out.println(tm);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //error is thrown here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
    {
        System.out.println(parent);
    }
```

}

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:86)

This program works fine if **this** is used instead of new Object().
I tried these following context methods:

```
Toast.makeText(this, tm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You can not instantiate an instance of an Activity.

Comment: pass a this instead of new MainActivity

Comment: The problem *IS* the `new MainActivity()`. Pass `this` as the `ItemSelectedListener`

Comment: @MuratK. what you been by that **this** and **new MainActivity()** is not same ?

Comment: It's not the same...

Comment: `//passing new MainActivity() instead of this (it may be the problem)` it is the problem. Why did you create new instances here all the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't instanciate a new Activity by yourself . You can handle the lifecycle of a Activity but not the instanciation, who is handle by the framework. Then when you use `this` you are passing the [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) instance which extend [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) that's why it's work in this case, whereas `new MainActivity()` create a new instance of the Activity different of `this`.

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.